# Inconsistent TableLayoutPanel resize behaviur

Tags: vb.net, tablelayoutpanel

I have two TableLayout Panels, placed one above the other on a form.  They each have the same number of columns (created at runtime) that line up with each other.  They are not docked, both are anchored in a parent TLP.
When I resize the form, most of the time both TLPs resize together and line up exactly. If I resize several times (usually between 5 and 10), the TLPs resize out of sync and the columns no longer line up.  If I resize again, the problem usually goes away.

[image: screenshot of how the error displays]

The Layout_Dates contains no controls, it is painted instead.  The Layout_Calendar is painted and may contain a number of controls, added at runtime.  The CellPaint events complete without error.

The TLPs are populated with columns like this:

```
    Layout_Calendar.ColumnStyles.Clear()

    Layout_Dates.Width = Layout_Calendar.Width
    Layout_Dates.ColumnStyles.Clear()

    For i = 0 To MyColumnCount - 1
        Layout_Calendar.ColumnStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, DayPercent))
        Layout_Dates.ColumnStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, DayPercent))
    Next

    ' make last column autosize
    Layout_Calendar.ColumnStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.AutoSize))
    Layout_Dates.ColumnStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.AutoSize))

    Layout_Calendar.ColumnCount = Layout_Calendar.ColumnStyles.Count
    Layout_Dates.ColumnCount = Layout_Dates.ColumnStyles.Count
```

I have two because one scrolls vertically and the other doesn't.

I have 'try catch' statements around my cellpaint events for both panels neither of which fire an exception.

I have tried checking the column widths at runtime, but these are in % and do not change.

I've put this in the form resize event:

```
    Layout_Dates.PerformLayout()
    Layout_Calendar.PerformLayout()
```

Does anyone know how to:
a) prevent this happening?
b) identify programmatically that this has happened at runtime?
c) deal with it when it does?

Comment: You are not exactly the first programmer to discover that automatic layout has a few sharp edges.  The core issue is that layout is *bi-stable*, caused by scrollbars taking away space when they are enabled.  Multiple layout passes would be required to deal with that.  With a nasty failure mode that this may never complete, switching back-and-forth between two equally valid layout choices.  Microsoft dealt with this by only allowing a single pass, that has the side-effect you observe.  By resizing by hand, you trigger another pass.  You really do need to use SizeType.Absolute to get ahead.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation @Hans Passant, I have changed it to absolute and created a whole pile of scroll bar related problems for myself in the process.  I guess I just need to take a deep breath work through it.